# Not able to get IMap Statistics in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

**Req**:
Need to get the memory occupied by the IMAP.

**Issue**:
I am connecting the HazelcastInstance using ClientConfig and retrieved the IMAP (sample).
I have created the LocalmapStats object in order to get the map statistics.
I am getting the values as zero rather than the actual memory size.

**Sample code**:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.addAddress("localhost");
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword(""dev-pass);
HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

IMap<String,String> map1 = hz.getMap("sample");
map1.put("key1","Value1");
map1.put("key2","Value2");

LocalMapStats mapstats = map1.getLocalMapStats();
int records = mapstats.getOwnedEntryCount();
long memoryOccupied = mapstats.getOwnedEntryMemoryCost();
```

From the above example i am able to get the memory occupied and mapsize value as 0 rather given the actual map size and actual memory occupied by the map.
When i was using **Config** to create the hazelcast instance i am able to get the map size and mapspace.But when i use **ClientConfig** then the scenario is not working.
Can anyone help me on working with **ClientConfig** to get the map status by using **LocalMapStats**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The stats are LocalMapStats, so they only show the entries owned by that instance. There are no global stats. And since the clients don't own entries, the count is always 0.

The only reason we provide those stats are the NearCacheStats which are only accessible via the LocalMapStats. Otherwise that method would throw an UnsupportedOperationException on the clients (and I think it did before the NearCacheStats were introduced).

Comment: Then how can i achieve my scenario to get the heap memory occupied by IMap.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no client support for IMap stats, it actually returns empty stats as you already noticed. Feel free to open a GitHub issue on the project page https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues